# beginner with latex - spaces between lines

Tags: thesis

i am dealing with the thesis writing. I know that \\ indicates single space lines.

The problem is that i can not find the way to make a "doublespace" between second and third sentence.
I read other similar topic but i think it is not the same problem(maybe i am not understanding texmaker very well).

The text looks like this:

```
\title{thesis
{something}\\ #here i need double space
{another thing}\\
{\includegraphics{/heraldic.jpeg}}
}
```

Any help?

Comment: `\\ ` means line break. Use `~~` for two spaces (or `\ \ `, or something even different).

Comment: Oh, you are right. And  only one  ~ for single spaces?

Comment: Yes, but beware: Those `~` characters are non-breaking spaces. Write them between two words and there can't be a line-break.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a short version: You can use `~~` which prints two non-breakable spaces. Or you could use `\ \`  which would force spaces, which could be broken. And just for protocol: There are other versions out there.

If you want a linebreak instead you can use `\\~\\` to produce two empty lines or simply use a `\\[\baselineskip]` which adds one additional line height to the document.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59373/discussion-on-answer-by-texnician-beginner-with-latex-spaces-between-lines).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\vspace{\baselineskip}` to add vertical space. Using your example, it would look like this:

```
\title{thesis
{something}\\ \vspace{\baselineskip}
{another thing}\\
{\includegraphics{/heraldic.jpeg}}
}
```

If you want to add a specific height, you can use `\vspace{12pt}` or indicate another height for `\vspace`.

Comment: Please add a few explanations and/or a minimal working example. As of now, this is more a comment than an answer.